# How to add a horizontal button row between a ViewBox and an Image in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I'm trying to add a row of horizontal button at the top of a form between an image and a view box but when I add the button it fills the image. I tried adding a grid to contain the buttons but that filled the image element. Does anyone know how I would achieve this?

I'm sure there must be a quick fix to this,could someone explain why this happens? I usually use the designer but I think in this case I should have a better understanding of the xaml elements and the properties.

This is how I define the layout for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="KinectKickboxingBVversion1.ConditioningFrm"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ConditioningFrm"  Height="377.612" Width="637.313">
    <Grid>

        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

            <Image Name="Image" Width="640" Height="250"/>

           </Viewbox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: Trying to add a row of buttons in the space between the image and the top of the window]

Setting image source to bitmap:

```
KinectVideo.Source = BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96,
                    PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel)
```

Comment: Add a stackpanel, set orientation to horizontal.

Comment: Between the image and the viewbox?

Comment: you need to understand XAML before writing it. you can't put it between the ViewBox and Image.

Comment: so where in the code will I put the stackpanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put it on the top of the form with no scaling, do this:

```
<Window x:Class="KinectKickboxingBVversion1.ConditioningFrm"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ConditioningFrm"  Height="377.612" Width="637.313">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefintion Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefintion Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Content="1"/>
            <Button Content="2"/>
            <Button Content="2"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Image Name="Image" Width="640" Height="250"/>
       </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

If you really want to add the StackPanel of buttons in the Viewbox, do this:

```
<Window x:Class="KinectKickboxingBVversion1.ConditioningFrm"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ConditioningFrm"  Height="377.612" Width="637.313">

    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="1"/>
                <Button Content="2"/>
                <Button Content="2"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Image Name="Image" Width="640" Height="250"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

Setting image source to bitmap:

```
KinectVideo.Source = BitmapSource.Create(colorFrame.Width, colorFrame.Height, 96, 96,
                    PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, colorData, colorFrame.Width * colorFrame.BytesPerPixel)
```

Comment: Okay so the the stackpanel has to be outside the viewbox,could you explain why this is?

Comment: A `ViewBox` can only store one child.  I will edit to show you how to add it inside the Viewbox, one second

Comment: okay interesting,I also noted in the last example that RowDefinition is not supported in WPF,is there an alternative?

Comment: Sorry, the last example doesn't have a Grid, so Grid.______ should not be set.

Comment: I have a further problem once I implemented the second example,the image didn't show when I ran the application,Is there a reason why?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is you're not setting the source of your image

Comment: I'm setting the source of the image as a bitmap source for the kinect sensor.It works when the image is in the viewbox on its own but when I use your implementation it doesn't work..ill show you how I'm setting the source in my question now.

Comment: I added the code to how I set the source of the image.Its coming from the kinect sensor.